# angular 2 : TypeError: this.form.updateValueAndValidity is not a function

Tags: angular, angular2-forms, angular-validation

I upgraded to rc.4 and am trying to use the new forms-api. This is what I get:

**"TypeError: this.form.updateValueAndValidity is not a function"**

The exception originates in the file "form_group_directive.js" within angular:

```
FormGroupDirective.prototype.ngOnChanges = function (changes) {
    this._checkFormPresent();
    if (collection_1.StringMapWrapper.contains(changes, 'form')) {
        var sync = shared_1.composeValidators(this._validators);
        this.form.validator = validators_1.Validators.compose([this.form.validator, sync]);
        var async = shared_1.composeAsyncValidators(this._asyncValidators);
        console.log('from within angular:---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------');
        console.log(this.form);
        this.form.asyncValidator = validators_1.Validators.composeAsync([this.form.asyncValidator, async]);
        this.form.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true, emitEvent: false });
    }
```

The output of the console.log-statement is a `FormGroupDirective` which just does not have a method called `updateValueAndValidity`.

Does the aforementioned error message mean anything to anyone?

Comment: Do you still use the `FormBuilder` class or the `FormGroup` one only?

Comment: I still use the FormBuilder, and I have the [formGroup]="myUserForm" set on the form-tag. Is the FormBuilder deprecated also?

Comment: No the `FormBuilder` class isn't deprecated. I think that it's because you mix template- and model-driven approaches to create your forms. I added an answer...

Comment: @TobiasGassmann are you mixing old and new forms? Can you reproduce in a Plunker.

Comment: Thanks @Günter Zöchbauer, trying to reproduce the problem in a plunkr (which I should have tried right from the start) made me see the problem. I had to remove the #userForm="ngForm" and then everything worked out fine.

Comment: That's the main reason why it's a good idea to create a Plunker with minimal code. It happens quite a lot that this reveals the cause :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think that you can use at the same time the template-driven approach and the model-driven one.

So I would use either the following:

```
<form  *ngIf="showForm" #userForm="ngForm"
   (ngSubmit)="userFormSubmit()">
</form>
```

or:

```
<form  *ngIf="showForm" [formGroup]="userForm"
   (ngSubmit)="userFormSubmit()">
</form>
```

where `userForm` is defined in your component class with `FormBuilder` or  `FormControl`. I think that this approach is what you need...

Comment: I had to remove #userForm="ngForm" and then everything worked